# Find records present in file 1 also in both file 2 and file 3

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, columns

I have three files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt` and they are of same format.

I want to select records from `file1.txt` which are present in both `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` based on column 2 and column 3 respectively to the output file `out.txt`.

Also, I need to create another file, `out2.txt`, with additional columns (column 4 from `file2.txt`, column 5 from `file3.txt`).

#### Sample Input:

`file1.txt`

```
1. abc 1 a f11 f13 f14 
2. abd 2 b f12 f14 f13  
3. abe 4 d f13 f16 f12 
4. acf 6 s f14 f15 f19
```

`file2.txt`

```
 1. abc 1 a f21 f23 f24 
 2. abd 1 b f21 f24 f23  
 3. abe 4 d f24 f26 f22 
 4. acf 6 s f23 f25 f29
```

`file3.txt`

```
 1. abc 1 a f31 f33 f34 
 2. abd 2 b f31 f34 f33  
 3. acf 5 s f33 f35 f39 
 4. abe 4 d f34 f36 f32
```

#### Desired output

`out.txt`

```
 1. abc 1 a f11 f13 f14 
 2. abe 4 d f13 f16 f12
```

`out2.txt`

```
 1. abc 1 a f11 f13 f14 f21 f31
 2. abe 4 d f13 f16 f12 f24 f34
```

Comment: There are many instruments but for the right choice let show examples of records, columns, desired output and so on

Comment: Hi @Costas, I have included an example. Please suggest me a solution. Thanks !

Comment: As I see records `abc 1 a` and `abe 4 d` **is** present in all files. Is it correct behavior?

Comment: @Costas Yes, those two records having same values in col2(1,4), col3(a,d). So, the rows from file1.txt needs to be copied into out.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution with `awk` (I will edit if needed because it is a little unclear from your question what are exact requirements):

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    m[$2,$3] = 0; z[$2,$3] = $5;
    next; 
}
FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
    if (($2,$3) in m) {
        m[$2,$3] = 1;
        z[$2,$3] = $5 " " z[$2,$3];
    }
    next;
}
{
    if (($2,$3) in m && m[$2,$3] == 1) {
        print $0 >"out.txt";
        print $0 " " z[$2,$3] >"out2.txt";
    }
}' file3.txt file2.txt file1.txt
```

We read the third file, create two arrays with keys column 2 and 3, first array filled with zeros, second with required value for file out2.txt. Then we read the second file and we check if key from column 2 and 3 exists in first array, if yes we change value from zero to one and we concatenate required value in the second array for file out2.txt. Finally we read the first file, check for existing key and we print interesting values in files out.txt and out2.txt so:

**out.txt** should contain:

```
1. abc 1 a f11 f13 f14
3. abe 4 d f13 f16 f12
```

**out2.txt** should contain:

```
1. abc 1 a f11 f13 f14 f21 f31
3. abe 4 d f13 f16 f12 f24 f34
```

Comment: Thank you, it was lot useful and served my requirements. I have a query in the command provided. Where are you reading the `ARGV[3]` `file1.txt` in the command ?

Comment: It is in the last {} section. We just do not have to explicitly point it with FILENAME = ARGV[3].

Comment: I have tried the below piece of code o identify the unique rows in `file1.txt` which are not present in `file2.txt`, `file3.txt` but I was not successful. Could you please have a look at it ? 


 awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
     m[$2 $3] = 0; z[$2 $3] = $5; next; 
 }
 FILENAME == ARGV[2] {
     s = $2 $3; if (s not in m) {
         m[s] = 1; z[s] = $5 " " z[s];
     }
     next;
 }
 {
     s = $2 $3;
     if (s not in m && m[s] == 1) {
         print $0 >"out.txt";
         print $0 " " z[s] >"out2.txt";
     }
 }' file3.txt file2.txt file1.txt

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to format the post and the code.

Comment: The answer is per your question and your desired output, it will be better if you edit your question with exact requirements because in the question the lines in desired output are presented in all three files.

Comment: Okay I will try to ask my new question in new post instead of hijacking this useful information. Thanks

Comment: It is not a problem if you edit current one, we can make changes to our answers also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23946/discussion-between-prradep-and-taliezin).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check this [site](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/diff3-examples/) about diff3 with this program you can compare 3 files as sample output:

```
$ diff3 parent.txt your.txt mine.txt

 ==== 

1:1,2c Hello, 

This is parent file.

2:1,2c Hello, 

This is your file. 

3:1,2c Hello, 

This is my file.
```

You can use

```
diff3 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I don't see how this could produce the desired output since diff tools operate on lines not on fields...

Comment: This might be useful for some other people and the OP's question was not clear first

Answer (score 3):

To select shared lines in all files you can use `grep` (`out.txt`)

```
grep -ho ' [0-9] [a-z] ' file3 | grep -Fof - file2 | grep -Ff - file1
```

select operatable field (as variant `cut -d' ' -f3,4 file3`) and use it to search it in next `file2` and `file1`.

As usual for joining 2 file use `join` command (surprise!) (`out2.txt`)

```
join -j 3 <(sort -k3,4 file1 | sed 's/ /+/3') \
          <(join -j 3 <(sort -k3,4 file2 | sed 's/ /+/3') \
                      <(sort -k3,4 file3 | sed 's/ /+/3') \
                      -o '1.4 2.4 1.3') \
          -o '1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.1,2.2' | sed 's/+/ /'
```

so to operate with 3nd and 4th fields together we have to concatenate it (by `+` sign e.g.). As `join` operates with sorted lines only so we do `sort` by 3rd and 4th fields.
Firstly join `file2` and `file3`, than result will be joined with `file1` and remove `+` sign by `sed`

Comment: Thank you, I am understanding your command and will use it.