# Error in file comparison - awk

Tags: linux, shell, files, awk

I have two files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`. I want to select records which are common to both `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`based on column 2 and column 3 and copy them to `out.txt` with additional column(column 4 from `file2.txt`).

#### Sample Input:

`file1.txt`

```
abc 1 a f11 f13 f14 
abd 2 b f12 f14 f13  
abe 4 d f13 f16 f12 
acf 5 s f14 f15 f19
```

`file2.txt`

```
abc 1 a f21 f23 f24 
abd 1 b f21 f24 f23  
abe 4 d f24 f26 f22 
acf 6 s f23 f25 f29
```

#### Desired output

`out.txt`

```
 abc 1 a f11 f13 f14 f21
 abe 4 d f13 f16 f12 f24
```

I have asked a similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204094/find-records-present-in-file-1-also-in-both-file-2-and-file-3) earlier on how to work with three files and extract similar output based on similar input for better understanding. I'm new to Unix world and been learning on how to do file processing. Based on that I have tried the below piece of code using `awk` but didn't work. Could someone please check and suggest, what went wrong ?

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    m[$2,$3] = 0; z[$2,$3] = $6;
    next;
}
{
    if (($2,$3) in m && m[$2,$3] == 1) {
        print $0 " " z[$2,$3] >"out.txt";
    }
}' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: In your example in out.txt shuld have 3 lines 6 s is also presented in the both of the files.

Comment: @taliezin Thanks for pointing, I have corrected it :)

Comment: `NR==FNR` is a more efficient and idiomatic way to check that you're processing the first file (unless the first file may be empty)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry, I am beginner to the unix world and tried to use awk for first time. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand what you meant to say !

Comment: You already asked the same question [a few days ago](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204094/find-records-present-in-file-1-also-in-both-file-2-and-file-3).

Comment: @Icd047 Yes, I did. Based on the suggestions given there for three file comparison, I have tried to code this command for two files and ended up in error. So, reached for help !

Comment: Please re-read the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour): "I'm new to Unix world and been learning on how to do file processing." has nothing to do with the question per se, leave it out, it is chit-chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are creating array m with values 0. You nowhere set it to 1, and you don't need to. You can just set value to entire row, e.g $0.
Try this:

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    m[$2,$3] = $0;
    next;
}
{
    if (($2,$3) in m) {
        print m[$2,$3] " " $4 >"out.txt";
    }
}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

**awk**

```
awk 'FNR==NR      {
                     a[$2, $3]=$4
                     next
                  }
     ($2, $3) in a{
                     print $0, a[$2, $3]
                  }
    ' file2.txt file1.txt > out.txt
```

**join**

```
join -j 2 \
    <(sort -k2,3 file2.txt | sed 's/ /+/2') \
    <(sort -k2,3 file1.txt | sed 's/ /+/2') \
    -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.3 |
        sed 's/+/ /' > out.txt
```

Comment: Thanks both worked well with my test cases.
How to use join when we don't know the number of columns in first file ? to specify for the "-o" parameter.

Comment: @Prradep Without `-o` `join` prints join field, remaining from first file, then from second. You are free to re-orginize it before joining or after with `sed`.